# why boolean not working with other modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have just a normal mesh and added 2 mirror modifier and 1 solidify modifier and with the boolean modifier its not getting difference. May i know the reason why its not cutting the hole. I check the doubles, normals yet to its not working. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fill "Only Rim" enabled.  This fails to draw anything but the rim.  In other words you're trying to Boolean Difference a single plane.  Difference is calculated based on normals.
See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html

[image]